# Стоит ли рекомендовать закрытие вопросов из очереди проверок, на которые был дан и принят ответ?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, очередь-проверок, домашки

В очереди проверок попался такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1205984/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-url-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) Полная цитата :

> С помощью const currentURL = window.location.href; получаю текущий
> url. К примеру он такой:
> .../index.html?FName=Sergey&LName=Ivanov&Email=s-ivanow@gmail.com
>
> из него нужно получить значения FName (т.е. Sergey), LName(т.е.
> Ivanov) и Email(т.е. s-ivanow@gmail.com).

Стоит ли рекомендовать его закрыть с такой тревогой?

> Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что
> вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.
> Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас
> трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы
> написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Или пропустить его, ведь на него уже дан и, самое главное, принят ответ?

Comment: Вообще, старайтесь поменьше закрывать (за исключением абсолютной чуши), лучше сосредоточьтесь на собственных ответах

Comment: Как же все надоели доводить «учебные задания» до абсурда :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Да, закрывать вопросы с ответами тоже бывает нужно.

Принятый ответ это не оберег.

Например, если вопрос "дубликат". Вопрос был ранее задан и на него есть ответы. Конечно, же стоит новый вопрос, даже если на него очень быстро дали и приняли ответ - закрывать "дубликатом".

Или другой пример, "Сделайте за меня домашку" - кто-то сделал, по доброте душевной, или от безделья, но вопрос то все равно отвратительно сформулирован и всем кроме автора (и даже ему, после сдачи) - бесполезен.

#### но не все подряд!

Но что делать, если что-то сделать хочется, а закрывать жалко, например, из-за хорошего ответа? Надо править и улучшать вопрос, так чтобы он стал достойным присутствия в Базе Знаний SO и мог помочь будущим посетителям!

Answer (score -2):

1. Нет.
2. Эта причина вообще не подходит этому вопросу.
3. Этот вопрос вообще не нужно закрывать.

Comment: Почему не подходит? Это явно учебное задание, и автор явно не пытался решить его самостоятельно

Comment: + мой вопрос не о домашках, а в целом о том, что делать с вопросами, которые вроде бы попадают под тревоги (например, под "необходимо конкретизировать" или другую), но на них уже дан и принят ответ.